# Deploying 32 bit application in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, web-services

I want to deploy a webservice in sharepoint which works only as 32 bit. It is working properly as normal webservice by setting "Enable 32-bit application" to true. Is it possible to deploy a webservice in sharepoint 2010 which works as 32 bit application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you do not use the same Application Pool as what SharePoint is using, yes you can consume it from a 64bit SharePoint solution by creating a web service reference in your Visual Studio project (or however else you're going to consume it, e.g. PowerShell).